# There are some data that Google Data Studio can't get from BigQuery

Tags: looker-studio

This is just my curiosity . On my google dashboard , there is one score card that doesn't get some data from BigQuery . This data comes from CV column and I can see 4 data in BigQuery but on dashboard just only 3 with same filter. I have experienced this kind problem before . Is this a bag ??

```
client_id | pscenario | orderid | cv_date 
AAAAAAAAA | main      | 11111111 | 2020-10-01
BBBBBBBBB | main      | 22222222 | 2020-10-02
CCCCCCCCC | main      | 33333333 | 2020-10-03
DDDDDDDDD | main      | 44444444 | 2020-10-04
```

```
Dashboard-filter

pscenario - main 
it should be 4 but only 3 is shown up on my dashboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by reconnecting data resource .